# Firebase fetch on Nuxtjs before rendering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a vuejs + firebase project.

I have a three vuex store modules which are
`back, common, front` My store folder structure is like this:

**src/store**

```
├───back
│   └───index.js
├───common
│   └───index.js
├───front
│   └───index.js
```

Without nuxtjs I can fetch user notifications like this

```
    fetchUserNotifications({commit, getters}) {
        let getUser = store.getters["common/getUser"];
        return firebase
            .database()
            .ref("users/" + getUser.id)
            .child("notifications")
            .limitToLast(5)
            .on("value", snapshot => {
                commit("setUserNotifications", snapshot.val());
            });
    },
```

But with nuxt js `getUser` returns undefined, I think thats because I have to fetch data's before the rendering.
I also added

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(store.state.front.user), 5000);
```

but everytime result is null.
When I check Vuejs Developer Tools on Chrome, everything looks fine and my data is there.

I have searched the docs and found `nuxtServerInit()` but couldn't figure out how to use it.

To be honest, I couldn't understand nuxtjs and need help to fetch data's easily like non-nuxtjs project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your question deals primarily with how to setup store modules in NuxtJS. Here's a quick example of how I might setup your root store module based on what you've shared so far about setting and getting a user and handling the `nuxtServerInit` function in the root store action:

```
// store/index.js

export const state = () => ({
  user: null,
  userNotifications: null
})

export const mutations = {
  setUser(state, userData) {
    state.user = userData
  },

  setUserNotifications(state, userNotifications) {
    state.userNotifications = userNotifications
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getUser (state) {
    return state.user
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
    return httpClient.get('/url/to/get/user/data')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        commit('setUser', data)
      })
  }
}


// where you fetch notifications in a component or page
fetchUserNotifications({commit, getters}) {
  let user = this.$store.getters.getUser();
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users/' + user.id)
    .child('notifications')
    .limitToLast(5)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      commit('setUserNotifications', snapshot.val());
    });
},
...
```

If you have any questions see the NuxtJS documentation on Module mode with Vuex store: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store